# Is it possible to know the SIM CARD state - for iPhone programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, core-telephony

I am working for Application where I need to know what is the STATE of the sim card inserted.

Is it possible for iPhone to know what is the current state for the inserted sim card ??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can, Apple does not expose any information regarding the sim, the cell radio, the network you are on, etc.

Comment: I am not sure but may be you can. As @Hugo mentioned just try Core Telephony also

Answer (score 1):

All the informations available about the telephony in the official SDK are in the [Core Telephony Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/_index.html). If you want to check for the state of the SIM card you can for instance call the CTCarrier methods which will return nil if the SIM is not currently available (if there is no SIM inserted, if the iPhone is in Airplane mode or if it is outside of cellular service range).

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is all in [**Core Telephony Framework**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/_index.html). If you want something more than the Core Telephony Framework, it may be possible using some unofficial way, but the application will be rejected if you want to submit to the Apple Store. Because it takes into account the user's privacy and security.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible and as per Appstore review guideline, they stated that Apps that collect user or usage data must have a privacy policy and secure user consent for the collection. This includes—but isn’t limited to—apps that implement HealthKit or other health/medical technologies, HomeKit, Keyboard extensions, Apple Pay, Stickers and iMessage extensions, include a login, or access user data from the device. Your app description should let people know what types of access (e.g. location, contacts, calendar, etc.) are requested by your app, and what aspects of the app won’t work if the user doesn’t grant permission.

Read : https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#data-collection-and-storage
Section 5.1.1 Data Collection and Storage