# Xamarin. Forms check if a Sim card is inserted

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.mac, xamarin.uwp

I would like to be able to check for all platforms (xamarin.mac, uwp, ios and android) if a sim card is inserted.

I know some tablets or desktops on the platforms above don't even have the option for a sim card but this would be fine giving the same result as having one not inserted.

However, there are cases in the app in which a sim card is inserted but there is no signal I do not want this to return the same response as the previous two and I already know how to handle this.

Having a sim card inserted but not activated I am undecided on how that should respond but I think either will be fine as it is more of an edge case. And I can test this later on down the line.

Thank you

Comment: You'll need to write your own service and implant it in the platform projects. Some googling should find you some answers. To get you started, you can use the [TelephoneManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getSimState(int)) on Android to get the sim state.

Comment: Just like Andrew say, and for ios platform, you can check [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865763/is-it-possible-to-know-the-sim-card-state-for-iphone-programmatically).